# jetpack compose - entry scale in animation for items in lazy row

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-animation

I'm trying to animate items in a `LazyRow` so when the screen launches, the items will scale in.
I managed to do so, but the problem is that it doesn't happen only when the screen is launch, but wlaso when the user scrolls the items, and they reappear with the scale in animation.

this is my code:

```
@Composable
fun ChooseUI(
    modifier: Modifier,
    navAction: () -> Unit,
    count: Int
) {
    
    ...
    
    LazyRow(
            modifier = modifier,
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 8.dp),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
        ) {
            items(count = count,
                key = {
                    it
                }) {
                CustomControlCard(
                    controlId = it,
                    modifier = modifier,
                    navAction = {},
                    packageName = packageName,
                    resourceFolder = resourceFolder,
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

@SuppressLint("DiscouragedApi")
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
private fun CustomControlCard(
    modifier: Modifier,
    navAction: (String) -> Unit,
    controlId: Int,
    packageName: String,
    resourceFolder: Resources,
) {
    ...
    val scale = remember {
        Animatable(initialValue = 0f)
    }
    LaunchedEffect(true) {
        scale.animateTo(
            targetValue = 1f,
            animationSpec = tween(
                durationMillis = 250,
                delayMillis = 100*remoteId,
                easing = LinearEasing
            )
        )
    }

    Card(
        modifier = modifier
            .size(width = 110.dp, height = 200.dp)
            .scale(scale = scale.value),
        onClick = { }
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surface),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.BottomCenter,
        ) {
            Image(
                painter = painterResource(id = drawableId),
                contentDescription = null,
                alignment = Alignment.Center,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(5.dp)
                    .fillMaxSize()
            )
        }
    }
}
```

so as I said, it works, but also it shows the animation when user scrolls the list, instead of just once when the items appears for the first time.

any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

For now, the animation runs every time the CustomControlCard recomposes (for example while scrolling). If you want to have it run only once, you can set the state of the animation like below:

```
var animated by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }
    
if (!animated) {
    val scale = remember {
        Animatable(initialValue = 0f)
    }
    LaunchedEffect(true) {
        scale.animateTo(
            targetValue = 1f,
            animationSpec = tween(
                durationMillis = 250,
                delayMillis = 100 * remoteId,
                easing = LinearEasing
            )
        )
        animated = true
    }
}
```

Here, once it runs, the state is set to true so it won't run again.

But remember to set the scale of the card to 1f when animated is true

Comment: hi, it's the same. still the same behavior.

Comment: I'm sorry! I wrote the code too fast. Check edited answer, for me this code works now

Answer (score 0):

Since the LazyRow is just a list that lazily loads items, I believe a safe approach would be to save/remember the state of each item at a given index (whether it has been shown before or not), and that state will be remembered until the entire LazyRow is gone. In order to save the state of each item, create a boolean-typed mutable state list, and store the state of each item at every given index, the boolean being false for default, and once its animated, it becomes true.

This code should work as expected:

```kotlin
Composable
fun ChooseUI(
    modifier: Modifier,
    navAction: () -> Unit,
    count: Int
) {

   val itemAnimStateList = remember { mutableStateListOf<Boolean>() }
   LaunchedEffect(null) {
       for (i in (0..count)) {
           itemAnimStateList[i] = false
       }
   }

   LazyRow(
       modifier = modifier,
       contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 8.dp),
       horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
   ) {
      items(count = count, key = { it }) { 
      
          val scale = remember { Animatable(initialValue = 0f) }
          
          LaunchedEffect(null) {
              if (!itemAnimStateList[it]) {
                  itemAnimstateList[it] = true //Making sure it happens once
                  scale.animateTo(
                      targetValue = 1f,
                      animationSpec = tween(
                          durationMillis = 250,
                          delayMillis = 100*remoteId,
                          easing = LinearEasing
                      )
                   )
               }
          }
 
          ...rest of your composable code...
       }
    }
}
```